# How to get maximum value from dataframe with numeric indexes and headings

Tags: python, sorting, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
df:

Unnamed: 0          0          1
0          0.0   0.000000        NaN
1          1.0   2.236068   0.000000
2          2.0   3.000000   2.236068
3          NaN   0.000000   1.000000
4          0.0   0.000000        NaN
5          1.0   1.414214   0.000000
6          2.0   2.828427   1.414214
7          NaN   0.000000   1.000000
8          0.0   0.000000        NaN
9          1.0   3.162278   0.000000
10         2.0  11.401754   3.162278
11         NaN   0.000000   1.000000
12         0.0   0.000000        NaN
13         1.0  14.142136   0.000000
14         2.0   2.828427  14.142136
```

I'm trying to get the maximum value from each set of data, the problem is that I generated this dataframe from several operations, but at the end the indexes and headings are numbers and I can not use `groupby` or `loc.` What I need is something as follows:

```
df1
        0
 1   3.000000
 2   2.828427
 3  11.401754
 4  14.142136
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.iloc` and `cumsum`:

```
df.groupby((~df.iloc[:,0].astype(bool)).cumsum()).max()
```

Output:

```
            Unnamed: 0          0          1
Unnamed: 0                                  
1                  2.0   3.000000   2.236068
2                  2.0   2.828427   1.414214
3                  2.0  11.401754   3.162278
4                  2.0  14.142136  14.142136
```

To just get the maxes for column index 1:

```
df.groupby((~df.iloc[:,0].astype(bool)).cumsum()).max().iloc[:,1]
```

Output:

```
Unnamed: 0
1     3.000000
2     2.828427
3    11.401754
4    14.142136
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you very much! the use of `~` is completely new for me, but I see its utility!!

Comment: @JonathanPacheco You are welcome. Yes `~` is very helpful in this situation.

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely use `loc`!  Problem is that you aren't paying attention to whether `df.columns` are integers or strings. Since you're having issues, I'm guessing strings.

However, what you're trying to do is not at all clear

IIUC

```
m = df['0'] == 0
g = m.cumsum()[~m]
df.loc[~m, '0'].groupby(g).max()
```

Answer (score 0):

**file.csv**:

```
0,1,2,3
9,6,7,
0,,,
5,6,2
```

Try:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=-1)
# keep only max per row
print(df.max(axis=1))
```

Output:

```
0    3.0
1    9.0
2    0.0
3    6.0
dtype: float64
```